# Given a python whl package, is it possible to retrieve it's development status information?

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

So I have a python .whl package, and I want to get the development status (dev, beta, release etc.) of it, is it possible to do that without scanning and parsing the setup.py file and only with the given package?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?